# Why margin and padding work properly in Opera but not in IE 8 and FF 3.6?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox

HTML Code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>CSS Test Page</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <style type="text/css">
    body
    {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    #int
    {
        width: 1000px;
        text-align: justify;
        border: solid 1px #000;
    }
    </style>    
        </head>
<body>

<div id="int">
Some simple text...
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

And the results:
**Opera 11**
[image]
Here it works!

But... 
**Internet Explorer 8**
[image]
...and **Firefox 3.6**
[image]

The problem is only if this code using as layout for Yii Web App...
Where I am wrong? Help, please.

P.S. kennel.cms.ua - this site is running on local web-server :)

Comment: UPD: The problem is if I using this code in Yii. I can't understand why...

Comment: I view it correctly with firefox 3.6 & ie7,8

Comment: It works as expected in both IE8 and FF3.6 for me...Also remember you can use the development tools on IE and FF to see what is getting set wrong.

Comment: Working correctly for me too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would, if I was you, do things properly if you really want to have cross browser support.

> ADD a **CSS Reset** prior to play around with CSS!

There are a bunch of them, just use it.

If you want to know what's the best CSS Reset I would encourage you to [**read this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116754/best-css-reset)

Answer (score 0):

Are you complaining because of the margin-top that exists in FF and IE, but in Opera?

try to set these attributes in the CSS.

```
display: inline;
float: left;
height: auto;
position: relative;
text-align: left;
width: 100%;
```

I think it will solve your problem :D